# How can I save the excel table to the database faster? and How to convert an Excel table to an object after reading it

Tags: json, excel, asp.net-mvc, object, epplus

There is an excel table with 20,000 row.
I want to add data from the Excel spreadsheet to the database.
With the following code, I can successfully save 20,000 row to the database in 2 minutes.But this is not fast enough for me.
How can I add data to the database faster?
Can I read the Excel spreadsheet faster if I convert it to an object after reading it?
Code that does not work fast enough;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using Proje1_1.Models;

namespace Proje1_1.Controllers
{
    public class ExcelToDbController : Controller
    {
        DenemeEntities db = new DenemeEntities();

        // GET: ExcelToDb
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Get(HttpPostedFileBase excelFile)
        {
            if (excelFile == null || excelFile.ContentLength == 0)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Dosya Seçimi Yapın";
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                if (excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelFile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Assets/PlateImage/" + excelFile.FileName);
                    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                    }
                    excelFile.SaveAs(path);
                    var package = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(path));
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                    var rowCnt = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                    List<plate_logs> localPlate = new List<plate_logs>();
                    for (int i = 2; i <= rowCnt; i++)
                    {
                        plate_logs pl = new plate_logs();
                        pl.Plate = Convert.ToString(worksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value);
                        if ((pl.Plate != "") && (pl.Plate.Length <= 10))
                        {
                            pl.Guid = Convert.ToInt64(worksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value);
                            pl.UserId = 0;
                            pl.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(worksheet.Cells[i,2].Value);
                            db.plate_logs.Add(pl);
                        }
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return View("Listele");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = "Dosya Tipi Yanlış";
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }}}
```

Comment: What is the execution time if you comment out this line ?
`db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: I solved the problem. I deleted the line of <code>db.plate_logs.Add(pl);</code> and replaced it with <code>localPlate.Add(pl);</code>. And I replaced the  <code>db.SaveChanges();</code> code with the <blink>db.plate_logs.AddRange(localPlate);
                    db.SaveChanges();</blink> code.